# Replaying function calls in C++

Tags: c++, templates, signature

I'd like to create a system where I can save all function calls into some sort of a file that I can later use to "replay" the file. For example, lets say each line in this file would be a function call, the first word might tell me what function to use and the others might be the list of arguments to the function. Then I could just open the file and run it line by line and replay those function calls. With templates, I know how to pass an arbitrary amount of parameters with arbitrary types, including arrays, but I am not sure what to pass in for the function. So far, this is my code which would work for the parameters passed into the function, the call of which I want to record into a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <initializer_list>

const int SIZE = 5;

static int counter = 0;

void dbl(int* a, int b){
    for(int i=0; i<b; i++)
        a[i] *= 2;
}

template <typename T>
void func(T t) 
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    std::cout << t <<std::endl;

    counter++;

    func(args...) ;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void func(T* t, Args... args) // recursive variadic function
{
    if (counter == 1)
        for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
            std::cout << t[i] << ", ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    counter++;

    func(args...) ;
}

int main(){
    printf("hello world\n");
    int arr[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    dbl(arr, SIZE);
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n================\n");
    func(1,arr,'a');
    printf("================\n");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want unit tests?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You will have to create an explicit list of function names, as strings, and the pointers to the corresponding functions. Then it's just a matter of reading the function name from your file, and then searching the list for a pointer to the function of the given name. If different functions have different parameters this is going to become very complicated, very quickly. But this is how this is done in C++.

Comment: @churill, I want to be able to initialise my code quickly without having to do the same computation every time

Comment: Do you mean something like [rr](https://rr-project.org/)

Comment: I wish you good luck to implement this. While I understand your wish (I would like to be able to do this easily as well), C++ as a compiled language does not allow this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Right, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Comment: @ThomasSablik not quite, I don't want to use this for debugging, I want to be able to have a file that works with my code for convenience in setting it up. This isn't just a debugging / testing thing, I want the code to be used this way intentionally.

Comment: Are you trying to write a script language like Python?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: You want to interpret a text file with functions and arguments. The functions are called with these parameters in this order. That's a simple script. You can check [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com/)

Comment: @ThomasSablik Right I get you now. That wasn't exactly my intension. I just have code that takes a while to set up every time because of the amount of memory and computation involved, and I figured the easiest way to initialise it would be just to save the function calls and all of the memory being set up and replay the setup from a file. I might end up doing this by making a python interface for my code, but I'd rather not do that given the option.

Comment: Template parameters should be compile time constants. You cannot read them from a file in the runtime code. I guess your problem is that you have a lot of pre calculations which you redo every time. Why not store their final state in a file and load that instead?

Comment: @JHBonarius That is indeed the problem I have, however, it's more complicated. There are two parts to the set up in my code. I have a different program doing precalculations, then driving my code with them, passing the precalculations to the right functions with the right arguments + precalculated data to set my code up. I wanted to be able to replay this process exactly with the precalculated data + extra arguments so the functions run in the correct order with the correct precalculated data + arguments, so they can set up the parameters my code will use.

Comment: To clarify, the time consuming part is, for the most part, the precalculations. But I also want to be able to be independent from the program driving my code, and part of doing this is being able to initialise my code with the precalculations without it, but instead of reimplementing the entire other program, I wanted to simply replay the calls that program was making.

Comment: Yeah, so the "thing" that sets variables and calls functions is called a "program"... and a file that that contains that program is an "executable". What I'm trying to say is: there are existing proven methods. Why do you want something else? I think your problem statement is very vague.